# How can i get justgage to refresh from Ajax request?

Tags: ajax, jscript

I have a dropdown which selects results from my SQL database, however on change the justgage keeps drawing a fresh gage.

tried calling my data from a function and doing an if else depending on if the gage object exists.  However whenever i select a new item in the dropdown it forgets my gage object existed?  (g1)

$('#record-select').on('change', function () {
    var self = $(this);

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://devops.robertbird.com/Michael.Forest/birdnest/partials/auditSummary.php',
    method: "GET",
    data: { record: self.val() },
    success: function (data) {


        // gets rid of weird character at start of string
        var cleanData = data.substring(1);

        // parse incoming JSON
        var results = JSON.parse(cleanData);

        doGetMyData(results);

    }
});

function doGetMyData(results) {
    filesize = results[0].ModelFileSize;
    modelhealth = results[0].ModelHealth;
    unusedfams = results[0].FamUnused;


    console.log(g1);


    if (!g1) {
        var g1 = new JustGage({
            id: "filesize",
            value: (parseInt(filesize)) / 1000,
            min: 0,
            max: 150,
            hideMinMax: true,
            levelColors: ["#01FF70", "#F2C80F", "#FD625E"],
            labelFontColor: "#5F6B6D",
            valueFontColor: "#5F6B6D",
            valueFontFamily: "Helvetica",
            noGradient: true
        });
        console.log(g1);
    }
    else {
        console.log(g1);
        g1.refresh((parseInt(filesize)) / 1000);


    }



}
```

});

I basically need to refresh the gage with new data not re-draw it.

any help massively appreciated (2 days into messing with this :()

Answer (score 0):

sorted myself

var g1 = new JustGage({
    id: "filesize",
    value: (parseInt(filesize)) / 1000,
    min: 0,
    max: 150,
    hideMinMax: true,
    levelColors: ["#01FF70", "#F2C80F", "#FD625E"],
    labelFontColor: "#5F6B6D",
    valueFontColor: "#5F6B6D",
    valueFontFamily: "Helvetica",
    noGradient: true
});

$('#record-select').on('change', function () {
    var self = $(this);

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://devops.robertbird.com/Michael.Forest/birdnest/partials/auditSummary.php',
    method: "GET",
    data: { record: self.val() },
    success: function (data) {

        doGetMyData(data);

    }
});

function doGetMyData(results) {

    // gets rid of weird character at start of string
    var cleanData = results.substring(1);

    // parse incoming JSON
    var results = JSON.parse(cleanData);



    filesize = results[0].ModelFileSize;
    modelhealth = results[0].ModelHealth;
    unusedfams = results[0].FamUnused;


    console.log(g1);

    g1.refresh((parseInt(filesize)) / 1000);


}
```

});